# ReactJS Render issue for Browser Extension Content Scripts on Chrome

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

I have made a browser extension which injects an iframe into the DOM that has some html in it. I have been trying to render a React component into the iframe, but it won't render and I receive the following error `Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.`

I've tried rendering to both the iframe and even straight to the DOM via content scripts, but I still keep getting the same problem. I know the component's render function is being called, because I placed a console.log in it and it displays the message; I have also debugged it and the breakpoints stop in the render function. In addition I added the lifecycle methods `componentWillUpdate` and `componentDidUpdate` and they are not even called.

```
//Index.jsx
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class Index extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  componentWillUpdate(){
    console.log('componentWillUpdate');
  }

  componentDidUpdate(){
    console.log('componentDidUpdate');
  }

  render() {
    console.log('render');
    return <div>Hello!</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Index/>, document.getElementById("g-root"))

// Including this code to show how I was adding the react component to the DOM if it is loaded immediately via manifest.json
// const app = document.createElement('div');
// app.id = "g-root";
// document.body.appendChild(app);
// ReactDOM.render(<Index />, app);
```

```
//webpack.config
const path = require('path');

module.exports = (env, args) => {
  return {
    mode,
    devtool,
    entry: {
      react: path.join(__dirname, './Index.jsx')
    },
    module: {
      rules: [{
        test: /\.jsx$/,        
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['env', 'react', 'es2015']
          }
        }
      }]
    },
    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, './'),
      filename: 'react.bundle.js'
    }
  }
};
```

```
<!--This gets loaded into the iframe-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>  
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="g-root"></div>
    <script src="react/react.bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
//manifest.json *included just to show that it has the same issue on page load.

{
"content_scripts":
  [{
  "js":["react/react.bundle.js"],
  "run_at": "document_end",
  "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
  }]
}
```

It should be noted that injecting the iframe, and the extension as a whole, worked fine until I started trying to add React to the project.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out it was an issue with an internal library having to do with rendering web components with my React components.